# RxJS detect long running subscription

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm currently using RxJS Observables / Subscription to perform HTTP requests as code similar to below demonstrates:

```
this.waiting = true;
this.doSomething().subscribe(
      (result) => {
        this.waiting = false;
        this.showResult= true;
      }
);
```

What I really want to do, is only set this.waiting to true on a predetermined length of time. In other words, you are only really 'waiting' if the Observable hasn't come back within say 30 seconds. Wondering how to achieve that. I see that there is a .timer method available, but that would only start subscribing after that length of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`timeout()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-timeout) and [`timeoutWith()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-timeoutWith) operators. These have no documentation but from their parameters you can guess what they do.

The `timeout()` operator send an `error` notification after some time of inactivity.

The `timeoutWith()` I think let's you replace the source Observable with another Observable after some time of inactivity.

Eventually, if you want to avoid these two operators you can use `Observable.race` that subscribes internally only to the first Observable that emits:

```
Observable.race(Observable.timer(30 * 1000).take(1), this.doSomething())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an operator that does this but this js code should do

```
const source = Rx.Observable.of(1).delay(1000);
const sub = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
setTimeout(() => {
    sub.unsubscribe();
    console.log('timeout')
}, 500);
```

you can play around with delay and setTimeout values.